# django select_related vs prefetch_related in tree like table

Tags: python, django, django-models, parent, hierarchy

I have a model like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)
```

I do the query:

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(name__contains=something)
```

And I want to prefetch 2 levels of parents above the categories.
So I will be able to iterate them and do

```
category.parent.parent
```

without extra queries.

In SQL that will be equivalent to LEFT JOIN with the same table two times.
How to do this in django ORM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `category.parent.parent`, you are following the foreign key forwards two times.  Therefore you can use `select_related`.

```
Category.objects.filter(name__contains=something).select_related('parent__parent')
```

`prefetch_related` would be useful if you were following the foreign key backwards (i.e. fetching the children of categories).

You may want to look at [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) if you are storing a tree of categories. It may make other queries more efficient.